# SMTP Socket Error or failed to set sender

Tags: drupal, civimail, cron, smtp

We are having an issue where our outgoing mail doesn't go out because cron isn't running, however, when we do a test email, the test email confirms that our SMTP settings our correct and we receive the email (when testing through outgoing mail settings.) There is a different [SE post about this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/136722/drupal-7-cron-does-not-run-civicrm-scheduled-jobs), my question is a little different. I have always been able to run the cron command manually from root which runs all the scheduled jobs:

```
drush -u 1 cvapi Job.execute
```

In case it's relevant, we use CiviSMTP for our SMTP service.

Today, I get an error:

```
Feb 06 10:05:58  [info] SMTP Socket Error or failed to set sender error. Message: Failed to set sender: b.1648.2597814.688997916ee6def3@civimail..com [SMTP: Failed to write to socket: unknown error (code: -1, response: )], Code: 10004

Feb 06 10:05:59  [info] Ignoring exception thrown by nullHandler: 10004, Failed to set sender: b.1648.2597815.43811c853a19c476@civimail.example.com [SMTP: Failed to write to socket: unknown error (code: -1, response: )]

Feb 06 10:06:01  [info] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(946): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::nullHandler(Object(PEAR_Error))
#2 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(PEAR_Error))
#3 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(577): PEAR_Error->__construct("Failed to set sender: b.1648.2597815.43811c853a19c476@civimail.example.com...", 10004, 16, (Array:2), NULL)
#4 [internal function](): PEAR::_raiseError(NULL, "Failed to set sender: b.1648.2597815.43811c853a19c476@civimail.example.com...", 10004)
#5 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(237): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:3))
#6 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Mail/smtp.php(295): PEAR::__callStatic("raiseError", (Array:2))
#7 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Mail/smtp.php(295): PEAR::raiseError("Failed to set sender: b.1648.2597815.43811c853a19c476@civimail.example.com...", 10004)
#8 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(714): Mail_smtp->send("Lawrence Chan <1.x.mailx1yy@gmail.com>", (Array:11), "--=_28b616505695aec5da019f0724c977c1\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative;\n ...", "1648")
#9 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(606): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob->deliverGroup((Array:1000), Object(CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing), Object(Mail_smtp), "20170203162117", (Array:1))
#10 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(192): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob->deliver(Object(Mail_smtp), NULL)
#11 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php(2934): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob::runJobs(NULL, NULL)
#12 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(317): CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing::processQueue()
#13 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_process_mailing((Array:1))
#14 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(161): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#15 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(92): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:7))
#16 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("job", "process_mailing", (Array:1), NULL)
#17 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(134): civicrm_api("job", "process_mailing", (Array:1))
#18 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(79): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
#19 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(99): CRM_Core_JobManager->execute(FALSE)
#20 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_execute((Array:1))
#21 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(161): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#22 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(92): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:7))
#23 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Job", "execute", (Array:1), NULL)
#24 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/drush/civicrm.drush.inc(1574): civicrm_api("Job", "execute", (Array:1))
#25 [internal function](): drush_civicrm_api("Job.execute")
#26 /usr/local/src/drush/includes/command.inc(368): call_user_func_array("drush_civicrm_api", (Array:1))
#27 /usr/local/src/drush/includes/command.inc(219): _drush_invoke_hooks((Array:33), (Array:1))
#28 [internal function](): drush_command("Job.execute")
#29 /usr/local/src/drush/includes/command.inc(187): call_user_func_array("drush_command", (Array:1))
#30 /usr/local/src/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(62): drush_dispatch((Array:33))
#31 /usr/local/src/drush/drush.php(70): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#32 /usr/local/src/drush/drush.php(11): drush_main()
#33 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there was a PDF attachment to the mailing, which exceeded the allowable size by our SMTP provider. Once I cancelled the mailing, everyting was fine.